# How to access api running in a VM behind the load balancer in Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, microservices, hyperledger-fabric, azure-load-balancer

I have a web API running in a Linux Vm which sits behind a Load Balancer. The LB has a public IP. I want to open a port in LB and map it to the port in the VM where the API is running. what kind of NAT rules, Backend Pools , all the configurations will i need to set up in the LB.

Comment: What is your specific purpose using public LB? Do you want to distribute traffics from LB to a web api which host one or more linux VMs?

Comment: It was the default LB provided when you create hyper ledger fabric template provided by azure. I wanted to expose the composer rest server from one of the vms. I figured it out. Cheers